# How to change the text of a Label - Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, button, label

I am creating a math game and want a score count in the top corner.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need the command argument, but you also need a function for the command argument to run. Something like this would work:

```
from tkinter import *

def increment_score():
    global score
    score += 1 # update variable
    score_addition_easy_number.config(text=score) # update screen

root = Tk()

score = 0
root7 = Frame(root)
score_addition_easy_label = Label(root7, text="Score count: ")
score_addition_easy_label.pack(side=LEFT)
score_addition_easy_number = Label(root7, text=score)
score_addition_easy_number.pack(side=LEFT)
root7.pack()

a_e_answer_2 = Button(root, text="8", font=("times", 30, "bold"), padx=190, command=increment_score)
a_e_answer_2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: hey thanks for the help, but it says that score_addition_easy_number (in the new function) is an unresolved reference - it says create a parameter, any ideas? Thanks x

Comment: @Katie010203 That is not a python error, that is some kind of linter warning and I can't help with that. However I can tell it's complaining about your code layout. I edited my answer to be a [mcve] so you can see the proper layout.

Comment: heyy I have everything from score=0 in a function, would this be why they are asking for parameters as I will have to pass stuff? Thanks x

Comment: @Katie010203 Hmm yes, that would cause it. The hack solution is change `global` to `nonlocal` and put the increment function in your function as well. The proper solution is to make a class.

Comment: what would a class do?

Comment: @Katie010203 a class is a container designed to hold functions and variables is a neat way. No offense, but I think you would be much better off asking in a beginner forum like learnpython.reddit.com The format there is much easier to have a conversation in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226528/discussion-between-novel-and-katie010203).